# Magento 2.2.5 Newsletter (/newsletter/manage/ ) management generates blank page

Tags: magento2, module, template

Newsletter (/newsletter/manage/ ) management generates blank page[image]

Comment: Anyone help me, Newsletter generates a blank page

Comment: It seems like your static content is not deployed properly try running this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f`. Instead of en_US if you have other language stores also than add them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since this question have been asked, but I faced the same problem with this magento 2 theme today.

To resolve this error, you must edit the file `app/code/MGS/Mpanel/view/frontend/layout/newsletter_manage_index.xml` and remove the layout argument in the `<page>` tag as follows :

Before :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns left">
```

After :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Hope this may help. Takes me few hours to find the problem.